# How to migrate MongoDB 2.4.14 file to MongoDB 3.6?

Tags: mongodb

I have a database file from MongoDB 2.4 and we want use this on mongodb 3.6. 
note: the file is original from the db path. Not from mongodump.
This process is messy as it requires doing so on many of our clients.

Any advice will be welcomed as I'm a bit lost in this process.

Thanks

Comment: You have only two paths. Upgrade your server version step by step (multiple server version upgrades in the row) OR dump data out, install version 3.6 and import data back. Both can be scripted.

Comment: @nemesis: Could you share which operating system you are using? I have built a script for linux(any flavor), I can share the same with you.